# "Add New" to foreign key field in django modelform

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm pretty new to this, apologies if i'm unclear....

running django, with bootstrap, and i've been fiddling with django-bootstrap. BootstrapModelForm is pretty cool, i didn't include the django-bootstrap stuff in my example, but i though i should note.

I have models:

```
class spam(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField()

class Eggs(models.Model):
   spam = models.ForiegnKey('spam')
```

I use a modelform,something like:

```
class EggsForm(forms.ModelForm):
   meta:
      model=Eggs
```

EggsForm allows selection of which spam will be referenced by eggs.
I noticed the admin interface has a cool way to either select or add another egg.

How can i get similar functionality into my create form?

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a standard form (not a ModelForm) for this? Add the "add new" as an extra option and catch it in the form's clean() method where you should then create the new object, redirect to another form etc.

Answer (score 1):

A little late, but I came across this SO question while looking for a solution and with some more internet adventuring, I found the instructions at this link which were great and it does exactly whay was asked:
http://www.hoboes.com/Mimsy/hacks/replicating-djangos-admin/

Answer (score 0):

In your template you can add a new (or "+") button, which can redirect or show popup or something like that shows another form to add new `Egg`.

Comment: I think the question is how you then would easily get the newly generated `spam` into your `EggsForm`...